# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.addAnonymousOperations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Hi im having while im trying to create a web application and i want to call the WSO2 identity server API RemoteUserStoreManagerService

The error is this

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.addAnonymousOperations()V
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.populateAxisService(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:42)
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.<init>(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:636)
    org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.<init>(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:625)
    org.wso2.sample.LoginServlet.authenticate(LoginServlet.java:83)
    org.wso2.sample.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:56)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.wso2.sample.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
```

I dont know the error but i imported the org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub in /WEB-INF/lib

is this the version of the .jar file or not?
Can someone help me..

Here is my code

```
private boolean authenticate(String userName, Object credential) throws Exception {
    if (!(credential instanceof String)) {
        throw new Exception("Unsupported type of password");
    }
    try {
        if(stub == null) {
            stub = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub(null, serverUrl
                    + "RemoteUserStoreManagerService");
            HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
            basicAuth.setUsername(basicAuthUserID);
            basicAuth.setPassword(basicAuthPassword);
            basicAuth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

            final Options clientOptions = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
            clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuth);
            stub._getServiceClient().setOptions(clientOptions);

        }
        return stub.authenticate(userName, (String) credential);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should check that you use proper version of jar. For example, decomplile your jar and check if there is desired method.

Comment: What is your IS version? and jar version?

Comment: @Bhathiya my IS version is 5.1.0 and my jar version is 5.0.7

Comment: @wind_gan how should i check and decompile it?

Comment: @FalconRyu You can use built in your IDE decompliler or download standalone decompiler ([this](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui), for example).

Comment: @wind_gan i just decompile my jar file and it has those method,

Comment: @wind_gan am i missing something ?