# RemoteUserStoreManagerService is not working in wso2 identity server

Tags: java, servlets, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Im following a tutorial from this site http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/02/how-to-write-a-web-application-backed-by-wso2-middleware-part-2/ im stuck. I got an error saying

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.addAnonymousOperations()V
```

i'm using the latest .jar file version.
My jar file version is 5.2.0 and my WSO2 identity server version is 5.2.0 
they are the same but still im getting this error. i can't continue to other tutorials because i dont know what will i do with this error..

Comment: This looks like a dependency issue.

Comment: Hi @shazin can you elaborate it more?

Comment: I assume this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366166/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-wso2-carbon-um-ws-api-stub-remoteuserstoremanag

 Can you try building the stub again with the wsdl taken from the IS server? 

Replace the wsdl here and build.  https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-user-ws/tree/v5.1.2/components/org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub/src/main/resources

Comment: btw, the jar version is 5.1.2 right?

Comment: Hello @FalconRyu . Did you find a solution?